# How do I formulate an SQL query to add a foreign key from a string in the parent table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I currently have two tables in an SQL database. A parent table (Categories) and a child table (Items) that currently do not have a relationship.

```
---------------------------
-  Categories             -
---------------------------
-                         -
-  INT(PK)   CategoryID   -
-  NVAR(50)  CategoryName -
-                         -
---------------------------

---------------------------
-  Items                  -
---------------------------
-                         -
-  INT(PK)   ItemID       -
-  NVAR(50)  ItemName     -
-  NVAR(50)  CategoryName -
-                         -
---------------------------
```

I have since added a Foreign key field (CategoryID) to the Items table and assigned a one-to-many relationship between the two tables not enforcing Foreign Key Constraint.

How would a structure a query that checks for the CategoryID from the Categories table via the CategoryName field of the Items table and assigns the resulting CategoryID to the new Foreign Key field for the entire Items table?

NULL testing for the Item.CategoryName field would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple UPDATE statement with JOIN will do the trick, something like this....

```
UPDATE I
  SET I.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
FROM Items I INNER JOIN Categories C
ON I.CategoryName  = C.CategoryName
```

Comment: It sure did!! Thank-you sir